# Inheritance / Polymorphism - calling method of subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the following, how can I make it such that the program uses the `draw` method from `MainMenuScreen` instead of the one from `GameScreen`?

```
class GameScreen {
public:
    virtual void GameScreen::draw() {
        cout << "Drawing the wrong one..." << endl;
    }
};

class MainMenuScreen : public GameScreen {
public:
    void MainMenuScreen::draw() {
        cout << "Drawing the right one..." << endl;
    }
};

class ScreenManager {
public:
    list<GameScreen> screens;

    // assume a MainMenuScreen gets added to the list

    void ScreenManager::draw()
    {
        for ( list<GameScreen>::iterator screen = screens.begin(); 
              screen != screens.end(); screen++ )
        {
            screen->draw(); /* here it uses the draw method from GameScreen, 
                               but I want it to use the draw method from              
                               MainMenuScreen */
        }
    }
};
```

PS: I do not want to make `GameScreen::draw` purely virtual, so please suggest something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I make it such that the program uses the draw method from
>   MainMenuScreen instead of the one from GameScreen?

You can't, unless you call it on a pointer or reference whose actual type is `MainMenuScreen`.

```
 list<GameScreen> screens;
```

declares a `list` of objects, not pointers or references. If you add `MainMenuScreen` objects to it, they will lose type information because of **object slicing** and polymorphism will not work. You need:

```
 list<GameScreen*> screens;
```

or, better yet:

```
 list<shared_ptr<GameScreen> > screens;
```

Comment: How can I change my for loop to achieve that? (assume all the list holds at the moment is one MainMenuScreen)

Comment: @Ben you can't just by modifying the for loop, you need to change the definition of `screens`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. So if I make the change that you suggest, how will I have to change my for loop? Is it enough if I also just add the pointer in?

Comment: @Ben I think changing `list<GameScreen>::iterator screen` to `list<GameScreen*>::iterator screen` and `screen->draw();` to `(*screen)->draw();` are the only changes you need.

Comment: It messes with a lot of the rest of my code in form of access violations. To add a screen to my list, do I now do `void ScreenManager::addScreen(GameScreen & screen) { screens.push_back(&screen); }` ? Cause that apparently leads to a Bad Ptr? I use the standard pointer (not the shared one).

Comment: @Ben no. `ScreenManager::addScreen(GameScreen* screen) { screens.push_back(screen); }`. And you create the new objects with `new`.

Comment: Well I'd rather use `&` instead of `*` as the formal parameter so that I don't need to check for null pointer. Or not? So how can I make that work?

Comment: @Ben You make it work by passing a pointer. I already provided the answer. :) There's no workaround.

Comment: With your solution it works. So I have to use the pointer instead of a reference? Do I have to check the pointer for NULL then?. Also, you have suggested to use the `shared_ptr`, could you explain why? I've never used it before so far, but it would probably be better!?

Comment: @Ben shared_ptr offers the advantages of automatic memory management and pointer behavior, that's why it's better. It's a smart pointer implementation.

Comment: Ok, so when I change the list to `list<shared_ptr<GameScreen> > screens;` like you suggested in your answer, then the code for adding that you suggested in your comment above doesn't work anymore, i.e. `ScreenManager::addScreen(GameScreen* screen) { screens.push_back(screen); }`. So how do I need to change that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to make `draw` *pure* virtual, but you do want to make it (or keep it) virtual. To go with that, you want to make `screens` a list of *pointers* (or possibly smart pointers of some sort) to `GameScreen`s rather than a list of `GameScreen` objects.

As it is right now, when you (attempt to) insert your `MainMenuScreen` object into the list, it's being "sliced" to actually *become* a `GameScreen` object -- therefore, when you walk your list, you're walking a list of objects whose actual types are all `GameScreen`; hoping to get `MainMenuScreen` behavior from any of them at that point is futile.

With a list of pointers, a `MainMenuScreen` will remain exactly that, so when you invoke your virtual function, you'll get the behavior of the actual type.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helps my understanding of why it couldn't work. I'm trying to change the list to a list of pointers now.

Answer (score 1):

You've fallen victim to [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). The objects in your list are only copies of the objects you inserted into it, and as each copy was made it got demoted to the contained type.

The way around this is to insert pointers (preferably smart pointers such as `shared_ptr`) into the list.